# Raster predict function error in R

Tags: raster, r

I am using a `method` to classify a raster using the `raster::predict` function in `R` using the `randomForest` function. Now when I pass the `model` to the `predict` function. It returns an error that the object `ID` not found.

How can I fix this error?

```
library(rgdal)
library(randomForest)

# Load training data
training = readOGR("path", "training")

# Extract values from raster stack and store it in df
DF = raster::extract(rstr_stack, training, df = TRUE) # Extract data values from the ImageStack

DF = data.frame(training$class, DF) # Add the known plant community to the dataframe

DF$training.class = factor(DF$training.class)

head(DF)

                  training.class ID VR.ms.20210407_transparent_reflectance_red
1                           SHRB  1                                 0.07171417
2                           SHRB  2                                 0.06323657
3                           SHRB  3                                 0.08368287
4                           SHRB  4                                 0.08835506
5                           SHRB  5                                 0.09549121
6                           TREE  6                                 0.08573120
  VR.ms.20210407_transparent_reflectance_green VR.ms.20210407_transparent_reflectance_blue CC_040721_MSAVI
1                                   0.06705832                                  0.03676167      0.16661084
2                                   0.06463767                                  0.04093402      0.17480536
3                                   0.06924891                                  0.04335563      0.10662237
4                                   0.06595835                                  0.04553290      0.01335551
5                                   0.06947684                                  0.04193549      0.10597064
6                                   0.07025375                                  0.04897893      0.02604642

### Random Forest Model
model1 = randomForest(DF$training.class ~ ., data = DF, ntree = 1000, mtry = 3, importance = TRUE, na.action = na.exclude) 

model1[["terms"]]

DF$training.class ~ ID + VR.ms.20210407_transparent_reflectance_red + 
    VR.ms.20210407_transparent_reflectance_green + VR.ms.20210407_transparent_reflectance_blue + 
    CC_040721_MSAVI
attr(,"variables")

ImageStack_rf = predict(rstr_stack, model1)
```

Error

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'ID' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trained the model on a data frame, DF:

```
randomForest(DF$training.class ~ ., data = DF,...
```

and that data frame had an ID column, and becuase you did `~.` it used everything (except `training.class`) as variables in the model.

Predictions need values of the same variables used in the training. You are doing:

```
predict(rstr_stack, model1)
```

and the raster stack doesn't have ID variables. So it can't predict.

I guess the ID is just the number of the data item you used for extracting the training data. It makes no sense to have this in the model. Drop it from `DF`, re-train the model, and try again.